# complex mysql constraints over foreign keys

Tags: mysql, constraint

It seems rational to me to stop users or bad codes from inserting invalid data, but I don't remember to see this anywhere!

Consider the following tables
[image]

- How I can make sure an order is always referencing an address that is created by the same user?
- Is this kind of constraint usual and recommended? I mean, Do I even have to care about it in the design?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE orders
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id, address_id)
      REFERENCES address (user_id, id);
```

A single row then cannot have a user_id and address_id that do not appear on a row together in the address table.

Yes, I would say you want such a constraint.

Comment: nice, but then this is a one time thing right!? Consider I had the same scenario for payments too, an order can only reference a payment by the same user! Can I use a column in multiple FK?